# Words without simple synonyms

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

Is there a word or concept that *describes* words lacking simple (e.g. less pretentious, less technical, less subjugating) synonyms, or more generally words without single-word synonyms. I'm looking for lists of words that defy "plain-English" translation, in an effort to identify "essential" vocabulary. I'm thinking of the vocabulary equivalents of least-common denominators.

Comment: Such words would have remarkably specific, if not unique meanings, so maybe "remarkably specific/unique descriptors."

Comment: FYI: Special English (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_English) and Basic English (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_English)

Comment: I don't know that this term is used for this purpose, but the word "irreducible" comes to mind. Also, fractions have "simplest forms," so you borrow that term.

Comment: If the word has no synonym but must be explained, how could it be "essential"? Do you have a simpler word for "essential"?

Comment: Yes, there is such a word but it's 187 characters long and can only be pronounced in Swahili.

Comment: *asynonymous* is used occasionally, sometimes with meaning "having no synonyms" (in genetics articles), and sometimes with meaning "not synonymous" (in logic articles)

Comment: Another word that comes to mind is _primitives_. It would probably help if you gave examples of the words that you're asking about. Are you thinking of words like _the_ and _be_?

Comment: I think he means words like *demonstrable*, which is difficult to replace with anything less grand without losing the meaning.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't one of them?

Answer (score 3):

Many of such words would be quite technical, not "primitives" or least-common denominator; and would not be essential to a " basic" vocabulary.  obviate, parallel, isosceles, gastroenterologist, pahoehoe, anemometer, sphygnomometer, pyroclastic, enantiomer....  These are not "irreducible", but it takes more than one word to " reduce" them. (of couse, now someone will come up with one-word synonyms just to refute my offhand examples).

I would suspect that invented languages would have a lot fewer synonyms than English, which has in many cases inherited or adapted multiple terms for the same thing from various languages.

Here's an article about Ithkuil, an invented language ostensibly much more efficient (more precise, yet more concise) than English.
http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2012/12/24/utopian-for-beginners

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking for a list of words that don't have synonyms. I've had no luck. I have however researched the idea for about two years now and the closest I have gotten to previous work on the matter was by the linguist Morris Swadesh. He is a little dated on his work.
Wikipedia has an appendix of "Swadesh lists" in various languages: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Swadesh_lists

These words tend to lack synonyms in their respective languages. Words like colors or body parts. There are verbs as well though.

Answer (score 2):

There is the word "Univocal" but I'm not sure if this is what you mean.

> OED
>
> 1.b. Of terms, etc.: Having only one proper meaning or signification; admitting or capable of a single interpretation or explanation; of which the meaning is unmistakable; unambiguous.Opposed to equivocal

> adj. 2. Now esp. in Logic.
>
> 1843   J. S. Mill Syst. Logic I. i. ii. §8   *A name is univocal, or applied univocally with respect to all things of which it can be predicated in the same sense*

Most prepositions have no true, or even close, synonym.

However, given the nuances of English, there are very, very few "true synonyms". English words "carry baggage" (often depending on the language from which they came), e.g. *king* is not identical to *monarch*; *quick* is not the same as *fast*, etc.  Also context plays an important part.